# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {CLSID} failed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, comexception

Complete Exception's Msg -

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

I have already registered this class using regedit.exe

P.S. -
I have `64-bit` computer.
I have already referred stackoverflow solutions and it didn't solve my problem.
I have added `Microsoft.Interop.Word`, `Office`, `stdole`, `Microsoft.vb.interop` assembly.
I was unable to change Target Platform to `x86` as there was no option in Target Platform's drop down.